# How to make a complex logo look good

Tags: logo, design-principles, branding

I worked with a client that wanted a mandala as a logo. I went through a lot of versions as I tried to simplify the request. This is what we ended up with.

I am not a pro at logo design, so I am seeking some enlightenment on how professionals like the awesome people here would have created this logo.

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrea! Welcome to GD.SE :). This question seems a little broad to me. Also "good" is kind of subjective to the user. Do you have something more specific to ask in regards to your logo design? (i.e. color, font, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Remove everything you don't need, first.

The two circles between the words, the grey border around the circle, the outline on the yin/yang icon, the serifs on the font (use a different, more simple font).

Then close up the tracking/kerning on the words, so they're more distinctively top and bottom, and more readable.

Maybe get rid of the yin/yang icon completely. It's a cliche, in the extreme.

Perhaps extend the purple out so far the lettering is white, and inside it.

Simplify, simplify, simplify.

Pare it back to the least you can get away with that still communicates your core tenets.